# Magento 2 foreach in Plugin not working

Tags: magento2, plugin

i'm trying to make a simple plugin, after method, as simple as that :

```
 class Plugin {
    public function afterAddUrlRewrite(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection $subject, $result)
{
    foreach ($result as $item) {
    var_dump($item);

    }
   return $result;
}
}
```

But this doesn't work !! the dump are returing the right values but something else is getting wrong. I'm getting 'Illegal state' in my log and no more info. Is there a way to loop over $result object ?

Comment: post di.xml also

Comment: Here is di.xml      <config>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
        <plugin name="net_gasoline_unique_url" type="Netgasoline\Uniqueurls\Model\Source\Plugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>

Answer (score 0):

It seems just impossible to plug on this function, that's it.